# Prevent pandas read_excel() to divide all percent values by one hundred?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

I was loading an xlsx file with pandas (1.0.5) and noticed that values with a percent sign (e.g. 0.3%) are automatically divided by 100.

I know how to load that column as a string but don't understand why it would divide the value by 100. Ideally, I'd like to have only the float value without the percent sign. For now I stripped the % and cast the columns, but there has to be a better way. This does not happen when loading the data as CSV.

```
df = pd.read_excel("testfile.xlsx")
```

input.xlsx :

```
|alpha|beta|
|:-|:-|
|0.3%|0.34%|
```

resulting data frame :

```
|alpha|beta|
|:-|:-|
|0.003|0.0034|
```

Comment: `pd.read_excel('testfile.xlsx', dtype='str')`?

Comment: dtypes change, but values are still divided by 100.

Comment: `0.3%` is `.3/100` which _is_ `.003`. Are you interested in the column being expressed as a string with the percent sign?

Comment: Seeing it spelled out makes it clear. Guess it's simply a data entry anti-pattern I'm dealing with. Ideally it would be `0.3%` into `0.3`. Thank you!

Comment: You could `df[["alpha", "beta"]] *= 100` but I'm not sure why you'd want to. This isn't an antipattern. Percent is like Roman numerals. They both need to be converted to actually use them in math. There isn't an antipattern here. Excel stores these as floats and its only its cell formater that shows you percent.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I used the term anti-pattern somewhat loosely referring to the original creation of my file. In the data I was given the numbers already are the percent values. Having the percent sign in each cell is an additional operation and yields the permyriad, so this is clearly a flaw of the data.

Comment: i faced same issue, did you successfully keep `0.3%` as string